# UTableView, Off Screen, not receving touch events when sliding onto screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I have a `UIViewController`, that has origin point of (0,0), this hosts some UI Controls and things work fine in it. I needed to add a sliding side menu behavior to this VC  ( like the FaceBook one ), so I decided to do it myself (I know there are third party libraries). 
Anyway so I add a `UITableView` with origin at (-300, 0), now based on some button click I just change the frame of the view and slide it to the right.

The Problem here is that no touch events are registered on the tableview that just slid over to the screen? I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: How have you verified that there are no touches being registered? Did you subclass UITableView and override touchesBegan:?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, basically if any view does not reside within the boundaries of its superview, it won;'t receive touch events, so I basically added a large UIVIew which encompasses both the tableview and the other controls, and made that the view appearing on the screen.